# How to make an "if" condition if the username is set as UNIQUE in the db in JavaFX?

Tags: java, mysql, sqlite, javafx

So I'm adding a new user to the database, I have made the username unique in the database so i wouldn't have to write a code for its validation.
Now I'm trying to use that error message when the user inserted is aleady used to make an "if" block, where if the username is already used to display a label that says just that and if its not already used to display a message and get me back to the login menu, but its not quite working for me, does anybody know how to tell the program to do something when the username is the same in the DB?
Here is my code:

```
package application;

import java.awt.Label;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;




public class SIngupController implements Initializable {

@FXML
private Label userLbl2;

@FXML
private TextField Nume;

@FXML
private TextField Prenume;

@FXML
private TextField Email;

@FXML
private TextField Username;

@FXML
private TextField Password;









 public static Connection Connector() {
     try {
      Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
      Connection conn =DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:C:\\Users\\munte\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\UserDataBase\\UserDB.sqlite");

      return conn;
     } catch (Exception e) {
      System.out.println(e);
      return null;
     }
    }
public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
} 
@FXML 
private void adduser(ActionEvent event) throws SQLException, IOException  {

    String query= "INSERT INTO UserDB(Nume,Prenume,Email,Username,Password) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?)";

    String nume=Nume.getText();
    String prenume=Prenume.getText();
    String email=Email.getText();
    String username=Username.getText();
    String password=Password.getText();
    try {
        Connection conn = Connector();
        PreparedStatement pst = conn.prepareStatement(query);


        pst.setString(1, nume);
        pst.setString(2, prenume);
        pst.setString(3, email);
        pst.setString(4, username);
        pst.setString(5, password);
```

~           This is what I have tried but it doesnt work, it's just executing all th code, dosen't even care for the else that I have added. So does anybody has any idea how to make a valid condition?~

```
        int i = pst.executeUpdate();
        if(i == 1)
        {
         ((Node)event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow().hide();
            Stage primaryStage= new Stage();
            FXMLLoader loader= new FXMLLoader();
            Pane root = loader.load(getClass().getResource("/application/Login.fxml").openStream());
            Scene scene = new Scene(root);
            scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();
            System.out.println("UserAdded");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Username already in use!");
        }

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }




}






}
```

Here is the error message when the username is the same as its in the DB, this is what i wanna use to make the "if" work, if anybody has any idea how to do so, please, help a brother out !

```
org.sqlite.SQLiteException: [SQLITE_CONSTRAINT_UNIQUE]  A UNIQUE constraint failed (UNIQUE constraint failed: UserDB.Username)
at org.sqlite.core.DB.newSQLException(DB.java:909)
at org.sqlite.core.DB.newSQLException(DB.java:921)
at org.sqlite.core.DB.execute(DB.java:825)
at org.sqlite.core.DB.executeUpdate(DB.java:863)
at org.sqlite.jdbc3.JDBC3PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(JDBC3PreparedStatement.java:99)
at application.SIngupController.adduser(SIngupController.java:92)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(Unknown Source)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1769)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1657)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8413)
at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:185)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:182)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:96)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:89)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3757)
at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3485)
at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2494)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:394)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:295)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$353(GlassViewEventHandler.java:432)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:431)
at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$147(WinApplication.java:177)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: You probably should do a tutorial about try/catch/exceptions. If a statement such as `pst.executeUpdate()` throws an exception the program continues with the next surrounding catch block that can deal with the exception. This means your program never reaches the `if` for duplicate user names...

Comment: So should i create a private boolean something that returns me true/false, the thing is how do i tell the program when the error happens to like acout it somehow? i dont rly know java, but i am pressed by time, i m working so i can pay my stuff, it takes alot out of me ... ill try to get more in dept java in teh future for sure, but for now i have to rely on what i can get

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If an exception happens, the program skips all the code until it reaches a `catch` that can deal with the exception. In this case you should add the code for handling duplicate entries to the catch clause:

```
try (Connection connection = Connector()) {
    ...
    pst.executeUpdate();
} catch (SQLiteException ex) {
    if (ex.getResultCode() == SQLiteErrorCode.SQLITE_CONSTRAINT_UNIQUE) {
        System.out.println("Username already in use!");
    } else {
        ex.printStackTrace(); // unexpected exception
    }
} catch (SQLException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace(); // unexpected exception
}
```

Comment: Hey man, I'm really grateful, I know that what im doing is not a good option but I'm working it out, thankyou for ur time and help! Indeed it worked.

Comment: One more thing, what does the ex stand for in ex.getResultCode?

Comment: It's the identifier from the `catch`.

Comment: EDIT : how do i add a Label insetead of      **System.out.println("Username already in use!");**, do i just declare it as a label then use label.setText? Cuz when i do that the window for signup when i action the button dosent load up anymore, works if i remove it.

Comment: you can replace this with any code you like whether it's opening a `Alert` or setting a `Label`'s text... I'm not sure what the issue with the label is...

Comment: Oke, I'll figure it out, I won't be annoying you with anymore crapp, thanks alot for ur time again !